# Moving tableview into existing window in Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, uitableview

In Interface Builder, I dragged a `UITableViewController` object from the library into the project. Then, a tableview popped up. How do I get that tableview inside my already existing window?

Thanks, I'm totally lost!

Answer (score 0):

That tableview is part of the UITableViewController, and is connected to its view property.  The second window pops up so you can set that UITableView's properties directly.

If you're just starting out, I'd suggest checking out a few tutorial.  The site I started learning from is called http://icodeblog.com/, and I'd also recommend the [Beginning iPhone Development book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430224592) by Jeff LaMarche and Dave Mark.  Also, if you have iTunes, the [Stanford iTunes class](http://cs193p.stanford.edu/) is a terrific way to learn in-depth about iPhone development, and it is free to download from iTunesU.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a view based application, the thing that you need is to add a uitableview from the library to the view. Be sure that you add uitableview, not its controller. It will be seen under dataviews

Answer (score 0):

You have to take UIViewController first and bind it with view. Then add UITableView in your controller and bind it with IBOutlet object of UITableView.

Then you have to set datasource and delegate of UITableView. That's all. Now you can access all the methods of UITableVIew inside your controller.

If you still find any problem then please let me know. I will definitely help you out to solve this problem.